# Reading text file one line at a time

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream, ascii

I have got a text file with a number of commands to parse through my system.  Each line within the text file is a command.

I would like to read the text file, one line at a time, where each line would be a command for me to act on.

I have reached a state where some lines are read completely by using `StreamReader.ReadLine()`, however some lines are not read completely.  Within notepad, there appears to be nothing wrong with the commands, and each one appears in one line like it is supposed to.

However, when opening the file with notepad++, I notice `LF` symbols within some commands, which instructs the text editor to start a new command, like so:

[image]

Those `LF` are misplaced (i.e. I do not want to start a new line when the `LF` is part of a command).  Is there any way to make the StreamReader interpret the file like Notepad?  As there are no line breaks in the middle of commands within Notepad.

Comment: @HassanNisar - The screenshot is taken from notepad++ - that data should all be on one line, not multiple lines. Within Notepad, it all appears on one line and the `LF` characters do not show.

Comment: [A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n").](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I guess you've to read each character and check if it's a 'real' linebreak or not.

Comment: In notepad++, Ctrl+H, select Search Mode `Extended`, Find What = `\n` and replace all. This will remove all line feeds

Comment: I would like to do it programmatically though @HassanNisar. The files are generated so I cannot manually remove the characters each time. And I do not have access to the source generating the text file. Also, within C#, I cannot see any special characters appearing in the string when I do StreamReader.ReadLine()

Comment: Whole file must be read in one string? or you got multiple lines having `LF` characters in one file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all text is one line then you could skip using `StreamReader`. 
Instead you can use

```
string sLine = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
sLine = sLine.Replace("\n", "");
```